# Show error message when custom Ribbon button is disabled

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, ribbon

I have a custom button added to SharePoint Ribbon. And there is EnabledScript attribute of the CommandUIHandler for the button. This attribute contains a javascript code to conditionally disable/enable the button. Can I set a tooltip message that show up when user moves the mouse over a button when it is disabled?

Comment: You can set the `ToolTipTitle` and `ToolTipDescription` of the [**`<Button>`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458366(v=office.15).aspx) element to show tooltip on your custom button and they show even when the button is disabled. Or do you want the tooltip to be shown _only_ if button is disabled.

Comment: Naveen, thanks for your comment. Yes, I would like to show it only if button is disabled. But if there is no way to do it I will just put more information to ToolTipTitle/ToolTipDescription.

Comment: One way to do this would be to check the enable/disable condition and based on that setting the `ToolTipTitle` and `ToolTipDescription` attributes on ribbon button. I raised a query on how to *Get object of ribbon button in JavaScript* on [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/130439/20540) and [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d83aefd-d1ee-4388-9766-03f11bff124c/get-object-of-ribbon-button-in-javascript) but haven't got any satisfactory responses. If you can gett object of ribbon button in JavaScript then this *might* work.